# Spring Batch Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-batch

I am writing a Spring Batch with idea of scaling it when required.
My ApplicationContext looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "in.springbatch")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:springbatch.properties"})

public class ApplicationConfig {

@Autowired
Environment environment;

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Bean
public Job job() throws Exception {

    return jobs.get("spring_batch")
            .flow(step()).end()
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource", destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() {

    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();



    return basicDataSource;
}

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
}

 @Bean(name = "batchstep")
 public Step step() throws Exception {

    return    stepBuilderFactory.get("batchstep").allowStartIfComplete(true).
    transactionManager(transactionManager()).
          chunk(2).reader(batchReader()).processor(processor()).writer(writer()).build();

  }



@Bean
ItemReader batchReader() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"reader");
    HibernateCursorItemReader<Source> hibernateCursorItemReader = new HibernateCursorItemReader<>();
    hibernateCursorItemReader.setQueryString("from Source");
    hibernateCursorItemReader.setFetchSize(2);
    hibernateCursorItemReader.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());


    hibernateCursorItemReader.close();
    return hibernateCursorItemReader;
}

@Bean
 public ItemProcessor processor() {
     return new BatchProcessor();
 }

@Bean
public ItemWriter writer() {
    return new BatchWriter();
}

public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){

    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor=new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
    asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(5);
    return asyncTaskExecutor;


}
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"in.springbatch.entity"});
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

    return txManager;
}

Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",       environment.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "false");

        }
    };
}
```

}

1. With above configuration I am able to read from DB , process the data and write to DB.
2. I am using chunk size as 2 and reading 2 records from cursor using
   HibernateCusrsorItem reader and my query to read from DB is based on
   date to pick current date records.
3. So far I am able to achieve desired behavior as well as restart
   ability with job only picking records which were not processed 
   due to failure in previous run.

Now my requirement is to make batch use multiple threads to process data and write to DB.

My Processor and writer looks like this

```
@Component
public class BatchProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Source,DestinationDto>{

@Override
public DestinationDto process(Source source) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+source);
        DestinationDto destination=new DestinationDto();
        destination.setName(source.getName());
        destination.setValue(source.getValue());
        destination.setSourceId(source.getSourceId().toString());

    return destination;
}
@Component
public class BatchWriter implements ItemWriter<DestinationDto>{

@Autowired
IBatchDao batchDao;

@Override
public void write(List<? extends DestinationDto> list) throws Exception {
   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+list);
    batchDao.saveToDestination((List<DestinationDto>)list);
}
```

I updated my step and added a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor as follows

```
@Bean(name = "batchstep")
public Step step() throws Exception {

    return  stepBuilderFactory.get("batchstep").allowStartIfComplete(true).
     transactionManager(transactionManager()).chunk(1).reader(batchReader()).
     processor(processor()).writer(writer()).taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).build();

  }
```

After this my processor is getting called by multiple threads but with same source data.
Is there anything extra i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is a big question

1. Your best bet at getting a good answers would be to look through the Scaling and Parallel Processing chapter in the Spring Batch Documentation ([Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html))
2. There might be some multi-threading samples in the spring batch examples ([Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples))
3. An easy way to thread the Spring batch job is to Create A Future Processor - you put all your Processing Logic in a Future Object and you spring-processor class only adds Objects to the future. You writer class then wait on the future to finish before performing the write process. Sorry I don't have a sample to point you too for this - but if you have specific questions I can try and answer!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to read a lengthy question. I think first I should spend some time trying Spring Batch out of the box feature to achieve multi-threading

Comment: Realistically speaking for you use case - option 3 might be easier. Spring Batch out of the box feature to achieve multi-threading work well when you can multi-thread the entire step i.e. your reader can read information in chunks

Comment: Ok, I can try out option 3.But as you say "Spring Batch out of the box feature to achieve multi-threading work well when you can multi-thread the entire step i.e. your reader can read information in chunks ". I am reading data from a HibernateCursorReader which provides me a option of reading data in chunks.Is this correct , then can you point me , how can I multi-thread my step?

Comment: If you can chunk up at the reader level (and I'm not sure if HibernateCursorReader provides that out of the box) but you could write a query to chunk up in general.

The most simplest way in this case - "The simplest way to start parallel processing is to add a TaskExecutor to your Step configuration, e.g. as an attribute of the tasklet:" - [7.1 Multi-threaded Step](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) 
e.g. to work off - [here](http://goo.gl/oOrcEj)
Specifically the 'load' step is multi-threaded in this example