# How to run spring-batch jobs threadpooled?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm starting `spring-batch` jobs using `JobLauncher.run()`.
Question: how can I threadpool those invocations? So that eg a maximum of 4 job threads may be running concurrently, and any further jobs are just queued?

```
    @Autowired
    private JobRegistry registry;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher launcher;

Job job = registry.getJob("jobname");
launcher.run(job, params); //immediately starts the job
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/backportconcurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) as the task executor used by the SimpleJobLauncher (the class that actually launches the jobs). This executor has some properties you can set, especially maxPoolSize.

```
public JobLauncher createJobLauncher() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();

    SimpleJobLauncher launcher = (SimpleJobLauncher) super.createJobLauncher();
    launcher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    return launcher;
}
```

Comment: what is super in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html).

Possibly a duplicate of [Spring Batch Multiple Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278109/spring-batch-multiple-threads) and [How to set up multi-threading in Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326695/how-to-set-up-multi-threading-in-spring-batch).

## Update:

I use the following code to start a batch job asynchronously. But I don't know how to limit the maximum number of executions as you mentioned.

```
TaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            jobLauncher.run(importJob, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The linked question is about multi threaded **steps**, which is *not* what I asked for.

Comment: SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor only runs the workload in a separate thread. Basically, it fires a new thread for the job it runs, it doesn't run it synchronously waiting for the answer.